# Create text modification system like the answerfield on stackoverflow

Tags: java, android, text, formatting, special-characters

In my android app, I want to create a text field with a lot of modification options (**strong text**, *emphasized text*, `enter code here`, [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com)) like on stackoverflow.

I thought about this option:

In the answerfield of stackoverflow, **strong texts** are wrapped in "** **" and *emphasized texts* in "* *".

> So I could conclude that every modification option have different special characters.

In the answer editor the special characters (**, *) are visible, so the special characters are inserted in the stackoverflow database.

> So the only possibility is, that the text is interpreted after receiving it from database.

**Is my guess right?**
**Can one of you give me a little bit android code of such a text modifier, so that I know how to start?**

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate About the Content in the textField and if you find a construct like ** then replace the following with a String in the whished font.